# Autopopulate a form using hyperlink

Tags: forms, auto-populate

I'm looking to autopopulate a search form entry using just a hyperlink.  I do not have access to site in question and when the form is filled in manually the link is http://siteinquestion.com/search

As an example it would be a case of adding a link to google.com that then automatically searched for the term I put in the link e.g. http://www.google.com/mysearchterm

Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**update, this does not work for the site in question.  If you're trying to do this remember to clear your history and use private browsing.  Sigh.

Okay, found the answer once I realised autopopulate was a tag.  The answer can be found here:

[Create a link that automatically fills a field on the target page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8252222/create-a-link-that-automatically-fills-a-field-on-the-target-page)

In a nutshell, use firebug or equivalent to find the input ID of the form.  then use query string to complete the form.

In this case, it looked something like this:

http://www.somesite.com/search?quickSearchText=texttosearchwith

Where quickSearchText was the input ID