# Can I autofill a form when redirecting from another website?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a website that handles donations to a club. The only way, however, to donate to the club, is through another website (the school website which I do not have access to). I sort of have two questions:

1. The school website has a query string. The only one I currently know of is ?fundDestination=[schoolname]. I want to be able to know all of the possible query strings so that I can input the correct amounts and the correct destination. Is this possible? If this is not possible, then maybe I can use question 2.
2. Is it possible to edit a website's input values while redirecting to it? I want to be able to have the values autofilled while redirecting.

Some extra information:

I know this website uses jQuery.

If you want access to the website, it is https://vsb.schoolcashonline.com. The specific link (without the query string) is https://vsb.schoolcashonline.com/Fee/Details/1869/196/false/true

Comment: Doubtful. You will have to check with the site owner to see if they offer an API or a method to do what you want.

Comment: Your best best will be something along the lines of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8252222/create-a-link-that-automatically-fills-a-field-on-the-target-page)